# Call parent component function from child's template angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've implemented the sort functionality for manage (grid) pages using `ng2-order-pipe` sorting module.

Ex:

app.module.ts

```
import { Ng2OrderModule } from 'ng2-order-pipe'; //importing sort module
```

manage.component.html: calling `sort()` from here

```
        <table class="table no-margin">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th (click)="sort('name')">Name
                  <span class="fa fa-sort" *ngIf="key =='name'"></span>
              </th>
              <th (click)="sort('contact')">Contact No
                  <span class="fa fa-sort" *ngIf="key =='contact'"></span>
              </th>
              .... and so on
```

manage.component.ts: `sort()` declared here

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response,Headers } from '@angular/http';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manage-enquiry',
  templateUrl: './manage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage.component.css']
})

export class ManageEnquiryComponent implements OnInit {

  //sorting
  key: string = 'name'; //set default
  reverse: boolean = false;

  //initializing p to one
  p: number = 1;

  constructor(
    //Private todoservice will be injected into the component by Angular Dependency Injector
    private http: Http,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {...}    

  sort(key){
    this.key = key;
    this.reverse = !this.reverse;
  }
}
```

Now I've number of components containing grid and would require sort functionality but I don't want to repeat `sort()` method in all my manage.component.ts file instead I want to put it in parent component like app.component.ts so that all the desired component can use by just calling it from manage template.

But when I'm adding `sort()` in my app.component.ts then I'm getting following error:
`ERROR TypeError: _co.sort is not a function`

I'm new to angular and don't have much idea about parent/child concept and how it works so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You added `sort` method inside `ngOnInit` method

Comment: @yurzui: sorry that was a typo

Comment: @yurzui: i.e. my manage.component.ts but I want to put it on app.component.ts

Comment: Use `@Output` event

Comment: @yurzui: how to use that?

Comment: As yurzui says, use @Output on the child and use `(eventname)="sort()"` syntax in template of parent to listen

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event